# Optimized environment for mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have my RHEL linux server(VM) running a 4core processor and 8GB ram running the below applications

```
- an Apache Karaf container
- an Apache tomcat server
- an ActiveMQ server
- and the mongod server(either primary of secondary).
```

Often I see that mongo consumes nearly 80% of cpu. Now I see that my cpu and memory is overshooting most of the time and this has caused me to doubt whether my hardware config is too low for running these many components.

Please let me know if it is ok to run mongo like this on a shared server..

Answer (score 0):

The question is to broad and the answer depends on too many variables, but I'll try to give you overall sense of it.

Can you use all these services together on the same machine at a minimum load? - for sure. It's not clear where other shards reside though, but it will work either way. You didn't provide your HDD specs which is quite important for a DB server, but again it will work at a minimum load.

Can you use this setup under heavy load - not the best idea. Perhaps it's better to have separate servers handling these services.

Monitor overall server load like: CPU, memory, IO. Check mongo logs for slow queries. If your queries supposed to run fast and they don't, you'll need more hardware.

Nobody would be really able to tell you how much load a specific server configuration can handle. You need at least 512Mb RAM and 1 CPU to get going these days but very soon you hit the limits. It all depends on how many users you have, what kinds of queries they run and how much data they cover.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run MongoDB along other applications on a single server? Well it would appear that if you are having memory issues or CPU issues in your current configuration then you will likely need to address something. But "Can You?", well if it is **not** going to affect you then of course you can.

**Should** you, do this? Most people would *firmly agree* that you should not, and that would also stand for most of the other applications you are running on the one machine.

There are various reasons, process isolation, resource allocation, security, and far too many for a short topic response to go into why you *should not* have this kind of configuration. And certainly where it becomes a **problem** you should be addressing the issue by seeking a new configuration.

For Mongo alone, most people would not think twice about running their SQL database on dedicated hardware. The choice for Mongo should likely be no different.

Have also suggested this be moved to ServerFault, as it is not a programming question suited to stack overflow.